# Communication between two user controls (one contains the other) with MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I'm developing a WPF with MVVM, .NET Framework 4.6.1 and C#.

I have two user controlers, one inside the other one:

```
<Grid x:Name="gridStartBatch" Margin="30" Grid.RowSpan="6" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Visibility="{Binding GridStartBatchVisibility}">
    <local:StartBatch x:Name="userControlStartBatch" />
</Grid>
```

I show `StartBatch` user control changing `GridStartBatchVisibility` value.

On `StartBatchViewModel` I have three properties that I want to pass to `FirstControlViewModel` and also I want to notify `FirstControlViewModel` to change `GridStartBatchVisibility` value to hide `StartBatch`.

Is there anyway to access `FirstControlViewModel` from `StartBatchViewModel`?

Comment: You do not have to use a third party framework. Look at the Command Pattern: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern and eventually use some sort of controller that inject your view models

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to communicate between view models and a lot of points what the point is the best. You can see how it is done:

- [using MVVMLight](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/27aaefff-e463-451c-87d9-37367a343e0e/mvvm-communication-between-viewmodels-using-mediator-pattern?forum=wpf)
- [in Prism](http://blogs.u2u.be/diederik/post/2011/01/15/Using-the-Prism-40-Event-Aggregator.aspx)
- [by Caliburn](http://www.mindscapehq.com/blog/index.php/2012/02/01/caliburn-micro-part-4-the-event-aggregator/)

In my view, the best approach is using EventAggregator pattern of Prism framework. The Prism simplifies MVVM pattern. However, if you have not used Prism, you can use Rachel Lim's tutorial - [simplified version of EventAggregator pattern by Rachel Lim](https://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/10/09/simplifying-prisms-eventaggregator/). I highly recommend you Rachel Lim's approach.

If you use Rachel Lim's tutorial, then you should create a common class:

```
public static class EventSystem
{...Here Publish and Subscribe methods to event...}
```

And publish an event into your OptionViewModel:

```
eventAggregator.GetEvent<ChangeStockEvent>().Publish(
new TickerSymbolSelectedMessage{ StockSymbol = “STOCK0” });
```

then you subscribe in constructor of another your MainViewModel to an event:

```
eventAggregator.GetEvent<ChangeStockEvent>().Subscribe(ShowNews);

public void ShowNews(TickerSymbolSelectedMessage msg)
{
   // Handle Event
}
```

The Rachel Lim's simplified approach is the best approach that I've ever seen. However, if you want to create a big application, then you should read this [article by Magnus Montin](https://blog.magnusmontin.net/2014/02/28/using-the-event-aggregator-pattern-to-communicate-between-view-models/) and at [CSharpcorner with an example](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/5ffb84/prism-event-aggregator-in-wpf-with-mvvm/).

Comment: @VansFannel if you don't want to use a third-party MVVM framework. 1) Implement your own Messenger class. 2) use events, and have the VMs subscribe to each others events. That said; MVVM is not just a single class which implements INotifyPropertyChanged. It is a design pattern which consists of multiple parts, and Messengers are a part of that. Using a third-party framework is just easier than trying to roll your own.

Comment: @VansFannel keep in mind that if you don't use a framework and you want to observe the MVVM pattern you'll end up having to implement all of the core features of a framework yourself and what do you think is better, using an established, peer-reviewed, open-source framework used by many developers or re-creating all that functionality in your code on your own?

Comment: which framework is the best one? I think I'm not using any of them because I have started using MVVMLight and it gets to difficult to understand for me.

Comment: @VansFannel in my view, `MVVMLight` and `CaliburnMicro` are faster to learn, but `Prism` gives more functionality and clearance. If your goal is just to communicate between viewModels, then there is no big difference between them.

Comment: I'm re-reading your answer and comments and I think I don't have so much idea about MVVM framework. Where do I can learn more about it? Thanks.

Comment: @VansFannel The good tutorials are placed in Rachel Lim's blog. They are very simple and told in simple plain English. https://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/05/08/simplemvvmexample/ You can see many articles about MVVM at her blog. For example, "Communication between ViewModels with MVVM", "Validating Business Rules in MVVM", "What is this “DataContext” you speak of?". She is like a teacher:).

Comment: @SetpUp Great! Thanks!