# How to create shared Model for 2 different Views?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm-light

I create the instance of my model in ViewModel2. This is sufficient for most of data. However, I also have some data, which is presented in different View, which is operated by ViewModel1. Should I just go ahead and create singleton pattern using for example SimpleIOC then obtain model instance from ViewModel1? If there is more proper way to do that according to MVVM concept I would like to know.

[image]

Comment: do you want to send data from `ViewModel1` to `ViewModel2`? Or you want to update one model and this update should be shown in both views?

Comment: Second case. Update model from one modelview1 and get modelview2 updated

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36621679/communication-between-two-user-controls-one-contains-the-other-with-mvvm/36621804#36621804

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an IOC container to hold the `Model` (or Data Access Layer to the model) and inject it into any `ViewModels` that require it.  This is the pattern used by the MVVMLight framework (see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991965.aspx or start a new MVVMLight project in Visual Studio)